# Static Logger in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, logging, zend-framework2

Laravel has a nice static logger interface that I would like to use (http://four.laravel.com/docs/errors#logging)

I want one *just like that*, but to use from the confines of Zend Framework 2.  Most specifically, I want all logging in source code anywhere to simply be:

```
Log::alert('string'); 
Log::debug('string');
```

Is there an existing package?  Can I write/extend my own?  Can I pull that codebase from Laravel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class:

```
class Log
{
    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();                           
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream('data/logfile.txt');  
        $logger->addWriter($writer); 

        return $logger->$method($args[0]);
    }
};
```

To call:

```
Log::info("my Zendastatic Log Message");
```

Sources:

- http://usman.it/laravel-4-uses-static-not-true/
- https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the Zend\Log\Logger with your own class and decorate it (like the same way). You can even put that into your Service Manager's services and get it.

```
$myLogger = new MyNamespace\MyLogger();
$myLogger->info('Informational message');

class MyLogger extends Zend\Log\Logger
{
  public function __construct() 
  {
    $writer = new Zend\Log\Writer\Stream('data/logfile');  //define log file placement
    $this->addWriter($writer);             //add the writer
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Where can I put my class so that it can be accessed anywhere from the global scope of my application?  I will want to create a static methods in my class and then call MyLogger::info("message"); from anywhere.

Comment: I have helper codes in a module. You can either create a module and put common lib code there and share it with the service manager or create a vendor folder/module as well. I dont track my vendor folder in my repos so I chose the module way.

Comment: I will need some help here ... I need to call info() statically.  Not via instantiation.  So I have created a module using ZfTool and called it MyLogger.  I put MyLogger class code file in the Logger/src/Entity folder.  Inside the class I've created: 
`public static function info($message, $extra = array()) {parent::info($message, $extra);}`
I call `Logger::info('Informational message');`
I get:

`Fatal error: Cannot make non static method Zend\Log\Logger::info() static in class Logger\Entity\Logger in C:\...\1.0.0\module\Logger\src\Logger\Entity\logger.php on line 8`

Comment: Zend's Logger::info() is non-static. So the only way I can think of is to have a static getInstance() method which supplies you a Zend's Logger object (Singleton pattern basically) and you can call it in MyLogger::info().

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this ?

```
 \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump('string');
```

Or this http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.log.overview.html

#### Modules

- https://github.com/Soflomo/Log
- http://logging.apache.org/log4php/

Comment: not quite.  Debug::dump is an interface for var_dump() that shows data to me right on the screen.  What I want is to write messages to a log file i.e. "/logs/logfile.txt" via using something like \Zend\Log\Logger::INFO('Informational message');  Although preferably just Logger::info("stuff");

Comment: Maybe you can find your way with these? : https://github.com/Soflomo/Log http://logging.apache.org/log4php/